# Is $f(x)=\begin{cases}x \ \text{if } x\in [0,1),\\3-x \ \text {if} \ x \in [1,2]\end{cases}$ continuous from $[0,2]$ to $[0,2]$? Yes/No

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider the  map

> $f : [0,2] \rightarrow  [0,2] $ defined by  $ f(x)  = \begin{cases} x \ \text{if 
>  x} \in [0,1),\\3-x \ \text   {if} \ x \in [1,2]\end{cases}$.

Is $f$  is continuous?

## My attempt: Yes

Only one - sided limits can be taken   at  $x=0,x=2$  and for the other points, the double sided limit can be argued.
By this  we can say  that $f$ is continuous

Is it true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that:

$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^-} x = 1,$$

and

$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^+} 3-x = 2.$$

Since

$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x) \neq \lim_{x \to 1^+} f(x),$$

we can conclude that this function is not continuous $[0, 2]$.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The limit from the left as $x\to 1^-$ is $1$, whereas the limit from the right as $x\to 1^+$ is $2$.